# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am very new to Spark Machine Learning (2 days old) i am executing the below code in Spark Shell i am trying to predict some value i see this error post available in Stackoverflow but i am not able to fix my code with the proper solution so posting the question again apologize for the same

**Input data:**

```
1.00,1.00,9.00
1.00,2.00,10.00
1.00,3.00,9.00
1.00,4.00,9.00
1.00,5.00,9.00
1.00,6.00,9.45
1.00,7.00,9.45
1.00,8.00,9.45
1.00,9.00,9.45
```

**Code:**

```
val df = spark.read.csv("/root/Predictiondata.csv").toDF("Userid", "Date", "Intime")
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DoubleType
val featureDf = df.select( df("Userid").cast(DoubleType).as("Userid"),df("Date").cast(DoubleType).as("Date"),df("Intime").cast(DoubleType).as("Intime")).toDF()
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
val data = featureDf.select("Userid","Date","Intime").map(r => LabeledPoint(r(0).toString.toDouble,Vectors.dense(r(1).toString.toDouble,r(2).toString.toDouble))).toDF()
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
val lr = new LinearRegression()
val lrModel = lr.fit(data)
```

**Error:**

```
 scala> val lrModel = lr.fit(data)
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce.
 at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
 at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
 at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:51)
 at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:72)
 at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:122)
 at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
 at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:90)
 ... 48 elided
```

Any help or Suggestion is highly appreciated.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Spark 2+ with *DataFrame API* together with [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler)

Something like this (haven't tested it):

```
import spark.implicits._

val data = spark.read
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .csv("/root/Predictiondata.csv")
    .toDF("Userid", "Date", "Intime")

val dataWithFeatures = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("Date", "Intime"))
    .transform(data)

val dataWithLabelFeatures = dataWithFeatures        
    .withColumn("label", $"Userid")

val lrModel = new LinearRegression().fit(dataWithLabelFeatures)
```

Also, take a look at [Pipeline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help!!...It worked after making few modification....Again thank you for your Help!!!...

Answer (score 3):

If your **Spark is > 2.x** import

```
org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT
```

and not

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT
```